# AtMega 328 SPI pin restrictions

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, avr, spi, pins

[image]

In the above picture for the ATMega328p pinout if Im using the microcontroller as an SPI bus master i know i will be using the signals SCK, MOSI, MISO and SS# which correspond to pint 19,18,17 and 16.

I am just wondering what other pin functions will then be restricted because the SPI pins are used?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about electrical engineering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will lose output compare 2A and possibly 1B, and the ability to use PB3 and PB5 as general outputs. Pin change interrupts will still be triggered, and the pins can always be queried for input.